# flattening an array? [].concat(...[array])?

Tags: javascript, arrays, webpack

I understand that `[].concat(...array)` will flatten an array of arrays, but I've been taking a webpack course, and in the code to load presets it uses the syntax `[].concat(...[array])`

My understanding of it is:

```
const array = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]];
const result = [].concat(...array);       // [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
const result2 = [].concat(...[array]);    // [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]
```

It's definitely confusing me because the course code (below) does work, but I can't see what `[].concat(...[array])` achieves?

```
const webpackMerge = require("webpack-merge");

const applyPresets = (env = {presets: []}) => {
  const presets = env.presets || [];
  /** @type {string[]} */
  const mergedPresets = [].concat(...[presets]);
  const mergedConfigs = mergedPresets.map(presetName =>
    require(`./presets/webpack.${presetName}`)(env)
  );

  return webpackMerge({}, ...mergedConfigs);
};

module.exports = applyPresets;
```

Can anyone give me a vague idea please?

Comment: `[].concat(...[array])` makes no sense at all. This is exactly equivalent to `[].concat(array)`. Which is weird since it relies on `Symbol.concatSpreadable` for detecting array-likes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit odd.

the `concat()` method takes each element from multiple arrays and adds them to a new array. So

```
[].concat([1],[2],[3]) = [1, 2, 3]
```

Now the `[somevariable]` syntax, places the `somevariable` into an array.

```
let arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
let arr2 = [arr1]
console.log(arr2) // prints [[1, 2, 3]]
```

And finally, the `...` syntax ([called spread syntax](https://dev.to/sagar/three-dots---in-javascript-26ci)) essentially disassembles an array, so its elements can be accessed directly

```
function myFunc(...[x, y, z]) {
  return x * y* z; // without the dots, we'd have to say arr[0] * arr[1] * arr[2]
}
```

Thus, the `[].concat(...[array])` expression you're confused about indeed accomplishes nothing; it places `array` into another array with the `[]` syntax, then immediately disassembles it back to how it was with the `...` syntax. An equivalent expression is `[].concat(array)`, which doesn't accomplish much since it has a single argument and the `contact()` method is called on an empty array.

Comment: Yeah, my JS isn't the best by any means, but it just didn't look like it was doing much. Was also more confusing because the author knows his stuff! Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 1):

Let me start of by saying that I have no clue why the spread operator is used. `[].concat(...[presets])` is equivalent to `[].concat(presets)` as far as I know.

However `[].concat(presets)` is probably used to normalize `presets`. If `presets` already is an array than this does nothing other than creating a shallow copy.

If `presets` is not concat spreadable (has the [`Symbol.isConcatSpreadable`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/isConcatSpreadable) property set to a falsy value), like `"foo"` then it is converted into an array with a single element and the output will be `["foo"]`.

If there are custom data types that are concat spreadable (has the [`Symbol.isConcatSpreadable`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/isConcatSpreadable) property set to a truthy value), but don't have all array methods. It can be converted into an array of size `presets.length` using this method.

Since the output is always an array methods like `map` (`mergedPresets.map`) can be used without worrying about the type of `presets`.

```js
const normalize = presets => [].concat(presets);

console.log(normalize(["foo"]));
console.log(normalize("foo"));
console.log(normalize({
  0: "foo",
  length: 1,
  [Symbol.isConcatSpreadable]: true
}));
```